# Find name of a windows process to kill it in task manager

Tags: windows, taskmanager, windows-process

Let us say my IE stopped working, so I go to windows task manager and go to Processes and select 'iexplore.exe' and 'End Process'. I can also use the 'Applications' tab to end the process but lots of times for hung applications, the application does not show up on the 'Applications' tab.
Now...I can use the 'Process' tab in this case because i know that for IE, the process is called 'iexplore.exe'. But often times I will open up the task manager to kill a program, but cannot do it because i do not know the process name in windows.
How can i figure out the name of a process in windows?

Comment: This is a chicken-and-egg problem, if you don't know the name then you'll have zero odds to kill the right process.  Less than zero.  Focus on getting your machine stable again instead of pursuing this route.

Comment: Please offer some tips on how to make the machine stable if you don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look under the description section for the process.  Most programs will use that to tell you what the process is for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do not see any 'Description' column there

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: For Win 7, whenever you are on the process tab you can click view and select column.  There you can check any of the options, including Description.  That is not an option in XP though.

Comment: Hey man, i am in XP :)..but i will accept your answer...it is a good suggestion for win 7